# JFrame slows down as buttons are pressed?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jdesktoppane

The code below shows my program that, when switches between methods home(), plus, minus(), `times()` and `divide()`, they `removeAll()` of the corresponding `JPanel`s , `addPnl()` `subPnl()` and so on - these being stores in a `JDesktopPane`.

I'm quite new to Java, and the idea behind my code is so that it is a maths program: you press a button, the `JFrame` removes the content from the `JPanel` that was displaying at that moment, then display the correct `JPanel` depending on what type of sum you want: addition, multiplication etc.

**My issue** is that, as you flip to the menu, then to another `JPanel`, and back, and forth, it becomes slower and slower to flip to the new screen/`JPanel`. **Is there a way to avoid this?**

There may be some bad practice in my code but, like I said, I'm fairly new and need to learn these things!

Many thanks.

I added `JPanels` to a `JDesktopPane` so I could have a background image on my `JFrame`:

```
desk.add( bgImg , new Integer( 50 ) );
desk.add( mainPnl , new Integer( 350 ) );
desk.add( mainG , new Integer( 350 ) );
desk.add( addPnl , new Integer( 350 ) );
desk.add( subPnl , new Integer( 350 ) );
desk.add( mulPnl , new Integer( 350 ) );
desk.add( divPnl , new Integer( 350 ) );
setLayeredPane( desk );
```

The different buttons link to different methods, all in my Class called `MiniMain`

```
public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent event ){

if( event.getSource() == addBtn ) { plus(); }
if( event.getSource() == subBtn ) { minus(); }
if( event.getSource() == mulBtn ) { times(); }
if( event.getSource() == divBtn ) { divide(); }
if( event.getSource() == menuBtn ) { home(); }
if( event.getSource() == noteBtn ) { MiniPad.pad(); return; }
```

Each of the methods start with some declarations that `removeAll()` of the content that are in `JPanel`s: panels that would be linking to the method

```
public void plus(){
mainPnl.removeAll(); mainG.removeAll(); addPnl.removeAll();
```

Comment: I think posting an SSCCE of your code might help us better understand the issue.

Comment: @AlexanderPower see [this](http://sscce.org) to learn what an SSCCE is.

Comment: It's difficult to tell from your code, but instead of creating each panel on each change, create an instance the first time you use it & switch between them (the instances). This should stop Ava from creating any short lived Objects which might be causing the garbage collector from running on each switch in an attempt to recover more memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you thought about a [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html), you can then create each different `JPanel` and simply *flip* between your `JPanel`s, it is better practice then removing all components from the `JPanel` each time and adding new ones:

```
//Where instance variables are declared:
JPanel cards;
final static String BUTTONPANEL = "Card with JButtons";
final static String TEXTPANEL = "Card with JTextField";

//Where the components controlled by the CardLayout are initialized:
//Create the "cards".
JPanel card1 = new JPanel();
...
JPanel card2 = new JPanel();
...

//Create the panel that contains the "cards".
cards = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
cards.add(card1, BUTTONPANEL);
cards.add(card2, TEXTPANEL);
...

getContentPane().add(cards, BorderLayout.CENTER);//add card panel to frame
setVisible(true);//show frame

CardLayout cl = (CardLayout)(cards.getLayout());//get cards
cl.show(cards, BUTTONPANEL);//switch cards to button JPanel
```

Comment: I've decided to give this a go. Thanks for the comments. They've made it a lot clearer :-)